# can a provisional profile created in one mac be used in other machine?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

My client cannot disclouse his developer account credentials. So he created one app in apple.developer account with my app's bundle id and then created a provisional profile.

He has sent me the certificates,provisional profile. Now i am not able to use my machine and out of my home and want to give a reply.
Is it possible to make an ipa with that given things?

Comment: Yes. The important thing he should export certificate from keychain, not just send you the downloaded one from member centre

Comment: to be correct: important is the private key. the certificate IS the downloaded one. It is merely the key that is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps,

1. From MAC System which was used to create a certificates from apple account, Open Keychain App
2. Then Select developer and distribution certificates and export both as p12
   file. You will need those certificates with export password from that
   MAC system. Install those in your MAC's keychhain then you can use
   provisioning profiles of that account.

Comment: to be correct: important is the private key. the above process will get you the key as well (in 99% of the cases ;))!

Comment: yes in 99% cases, those exported certificates will have Private keys as I mentioned - MAC System which was already used to create a certificates from apple account.